# How to add custom markers from server to google map? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working on app, which shows users position and loads nearby places. Places are obtained from the server by coordinate. So my question is how to display them as custom markers with correct size? I'm loading coordinates to an array and then show them on map. This is how far I've got: 
[image]

Marker gets bigger on scrolling.

This is where I set the marker:

```
 let coordinates = spotCoordinates
let image = UIImage(named: "Dog")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
for coord in coordinates {
   let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord.latitude,longitude:coord.longitude)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.map = spotsParentView.mapView
    marker.icon = image
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add marker icons and positions in array like this:

```
 let marker = GMSMarkerInfo()
  marker.icon = UIImage(named: "locationPinNeon")
   self.markerArray.append(marker)
```

Then to display markers in locations which you got from server on map you have to implement below code:

```
 let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: Double(self.lat)!, longitude: Double(self.long)!, zoom: 5.0)
                self.mapView.camera = camera

                delay(seconds: 1) { () -> () in
                    //fit map to markers
                    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
                    for marker in self.markerArray {
                        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
                    }
                    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 100.0)
                    self.mapView.animate(with: update)
                }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response, but I can't see how it answers my question. 1. I'm already have images, my purpose is to show them on map. 2. You've provided an extension to UIImageView, but then, in functions body, you call class function. If I didn't get something, please help me understand your answer

Comment: So are you using google clustering to show near by places?

Comment: I haven't add google clustering yet. Just loading coordinates from server and then, setting them on map

Comment: I have edited the answer look into it and update your code according.. hope this helps you.

Comment: I did it in almost same way and your answer helps much to improve my code. Thank you!